# Xcode and iOS Simulator versions pulling outdated Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, sencha-touch

Sometimes when I run 'sencha app build -run native' it pulls an outdated Cordova version of my project. 
The same happens when I double click on /project/cordova/platforms/ios/project.xcodeproj.

I tried 'sencha app refresh' but it is still outdated.

I don't think it is Cordova related, since my production version ('sencha app build production') remains outdated as well.

I'm dealing with it since I started the project (my first sencha touch project) a couple of weeks ago.

I really don't know what I do or what happens that actually updates my Cordova version, but I know that after some time it will be updated, maybe today, maybe tomorrow, I don't know.

It is really annoying specially when I have to show the latest version for my client and I simply can't (or don't know how to) do that. (That's why I schedule our meetings only after my iOS Simulator version gets updated)

I'm new on Sencha Touch and I hope that I'm doing something wrong.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

cordova
3.5.0-0.2.6

Sencha
2.3.1

Sencha Cmd 
v4.0.4.84

Comment: Did you run a "clean" build in either XCode or Sencha Cmd? `sencha ant clean` should be what you need.

Comment: Didnt work as well. Do you know if I can do that manually? What folders should I remove to stop using that outdated version?

Comment: When you run `sencha app build`, normally that outputs the app under `/build/`. However since you're using Cordova integration with Cmd, the hybrid app is output under `/cordova/platforms/xyz/`. Can you open a thread on the Sencha forums? I can help you better there - just post the link in the comments here.

Comment: I think I don't have privileges to do that. Only with a paid subscription?

Comment: Anyone can post to the sencha touch forums. You just need to create an account.

Comment: I am still not able to post there.

"you do not have permission to access this page. This could be due to one of several reasons:
Your user account may not have sufficient privileges to access this page. Are you trying to edit someone else's post, access administrative features or some other privileged system?
If you are trying to post, the administrator may have disabled your account, or it may be awaiting activation."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my mistake!
I will explain here because it might be useful for someone.

I was complaining that my `view/home.js` was outdated, right?
That's because I had a previous `view/home.js` and decided to change it completely.
So I renamed it to `view/homeOLD.js` and created a new one called `view/home.js` (both classes called `Ext.define('Shopping.view.Home',`.

When I browse to `http://localhost/shopping` my new `view/home.js` is called, but my Xcode (and ios simulator) seems to search for a class called `Shopping.view.Home`, wherever it is (inside view/ folder) and, I guess, it found first my file called `homeOLD.js` so it was discarding any other file that may have a class called `Shopping.view.Home`.
That's why my Xcode and Simulator version was never updated, because it was looking for (and finding) a class a file other than `view/home.hj`.

Lesson learned: COMMENT (or delete) but not rename files when we and to discard it.

Thank you, guys and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience getting a really clean build with both Sencha and Cordova can be a bit tricky. Here are a couple of possibilities to check: (1) make sure your platforms are on the correct version and (2) delete the `build` folders to force a really clean build.

**Check Your Platform Versions**

Run `cordova platform list` command in your cordova directory to get a list platforms you're targeting, and more importantly, the cordova versions you're building each target for. You should see output like this:

```
velouria:cordova sherb$ cordova platform list
Installed platforms: android 3.5.0, ios 3.5.0
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, firefoxos
```

You can upgrade each platform with `cordova platform update ios` or upgrade your entire project with `cordova platform update`.

**Get a Really Clean Build**

Navigate to `[project]/cordova/platforms/ios` and delete `build` and `CordovaLib/build`. Also delete the `build` folders for any other Xcode projects that may be there. Cordova does provide a clean script in `platforms/ios/cordova/clean` that you can run from the command-line, but in my experience it doesn't quite get everything.

Now `cd [project dir]` and run Sencha's build command `sencha app build -c native` (where `-c` is for 'clean'), then `cd [project]/cordova` and run the cordova build command `cordova build ios`.

Comment: Tried... No success.

"Hugo-Soaress-MacBook-Pro:cordova hugosoares$ cordova platform list
Installed platforms: ios 3.5.0
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, android, blackberry10, firefoxos
Hugo-Soaress-MacBook-Pro:cordova hugosoares$ cordova platform update ios
iOS project is now at version 3.5.0"

Comment: @Ramos, I added notes on getting a really clean build - HTH!

Comment: Same thing... 
I`m afraid I have to delete [project]/cordova folder and add ios platform again and (unfortunately) reconfigure everything again in Xcode (icons, splash, etc).
Thank you, sherb, for your help.